# Change value of <input> which has only class and index

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an HTML file where I have four input fields and none of them has an id. I want to change the value of those input fields. Below is the implementation of the input field. The index is different for all four input field.

```
<input class="digit" index="0" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="9">
```

I know how to do it if I have "id" by using below, but I dont know how to do if I dont have an id.

```
document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";
```

I tried below but it's not working.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('digit').setAttribute("value", "2");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `document.querySelector[All]()` and select the `index` attribute

```js
 document.querySelector('input[index="0"]').value = 9;
```

```html
<input class="digit" index="0" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="9">
<input class="digit" index="1" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="9">
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elements. You can do something like this to change all the inputs of that class.

```js
let digitElems = document.getElementsByClassName('digit');

Array.from(digitElems).forEach(function (el) {
  el.setAttribute("value", 2);
})
```

```html
<input class="digit" index="0" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="9">
<input class="digit" index="0" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="9">
<input class="digit" index="0" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="9">
<input class="digit" index="0" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="9">
```